# Python- Getting output from subprocess and comparing it with an IF

Tags: python, subprocess

I already know Java and decided to try out some Python on Linux to suit all my needs.

Made a simple little proggy to check if the script is running as root or not, and if it's not we ask for the password.

```
    import subprocess;
process = subprocess.Popen(['id', '-u'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
uid, err = process.communicate()
print(uid)

if uid != 0:
    lpass = raw_input("\nYou are NOT running this script as root.\n Please enter your Linux password:")
```

This is the output:

```
1000 
You are NOT running this script as root.
 Please enter your Linux password:
```

Now, the problem is that the IF doesn't work, or more precisely the `uid != 0` doesn't do what I want it to do. The IF statement simply always comes out as false, even when I run the script as root. I've also tried `uid == 1000` which also failed.

I suspect this is because I'm comparing 'something else' with a string or an integer, but I have no idea how to get that something else or how to convert it, but this is just layman's speculation. Halp.

Answer (score 0):

`Popen.communicate` return a tuple of strings or bytes in 3.x.

The `uid` seems to be something like `b'1000\n'`. So use `if int(uid.strip()) != 0`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but how did you know what it returns? I'm looking at http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html and there's nothing on the communicate function. I've also tried using type() but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: When the documentation doesn't mention, I google it. If google can work. I try it myself. You code is not long, so I tried it in both 2.x and 3.x. The code works well on my PC. :) Stupid yeah.@user2579116

Comment: Heh, that's going to be kind of confusing then :3 Anyways, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. If you neet to check the effective user id, use:

```
import os
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    ...
```

Using `subprocess` for this is not the right way.